# NoReverseMatch at /cart/ Reverse for 'cart_add' with arguments '('',)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['cart/add/(?P<house_id>[0-9]+)/$']

Tags: python, django

Hi am trying to create an online house shopping site but when i to add the items(houses) to the cart i get the following error

```
    Internal Server Error: /cart/
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\user\myprojects\byarent\env\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 34, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "C:\Users\user\myprojects\byarent\env\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 126, in _get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "C:\Users\user\myprojects\byarent\env\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 124, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\user\myprojects\byarent\buyandrent\cart\views.py", line 31, in cart_detail
    return render(request, 'cart/detail.html', {'cart': cart})
  File "C:\Users\user\myprojects\byarent\env\lib\site-packages\django\shortcuts.py", line 36, in render
    content = loader.render_to_string(template_name, context, request, using=using)
  File "C:\Users\user\myprojects\byarent\env\lib\site-packages\django\template\loader.py", line 62, in render_to_string
    return template.render(context, request)
  File "C:\Users\user\myprojects\byarent\env\lib\site-packages\django\template\backends\django.py", line 61, in render
    return self.template.render(context)
  File "C:\Users\user\myprojects\byarent\env\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 171, in render
    return self._render(context)
  File "C:\Users\user\myprojects\byarent\env\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 163, in _render
    return self.nodelist.render(context)
  File "C:\Users\user\myprojects\byarent\env\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 937, in render
    bit = node.render_annotated(context)
  File "C:\Users\user\myprojects\byarent\env\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 904, in render_annotated
    return self.render(context)
  File "C:\Users\user\myprojects\byarent\env\lib\site-packages\django\template\loader_tags.py", line 150, in render
    return compiled_parent._render(context)
  File "C:\Users\user\myprojects\byarent\env\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 163, in _render
    return self.nodelist.render(context)
  File "C:\Users\user\myprojects\byarent\env\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 937, in render
    bit = node.render_annotated(context)
  File "C:\Users\user\myprojects\byarent\env\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 904, in render_annotated
    return self.render(context)
  File "C:\Users\user\myprojects\byarent\env\lib\site-packages\django\template\loader_tags.py", line 62, in render
    result = block.nodelist.render(context)
  File "C:\Users\user\myprojects\byarent\env\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 937, in render
    bit = node.render_annotated(context)
  File "C:\Users\user\myprojects\byarent\env\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 904, in render_annotated
    return self.render(context)
  File "C:\Users\user\myprojects\byarent\env\lib\site-packages\django\template\defaulttags.py", line 209, in render
    nodelist.append(node.render_annotated(context))
  File "C:\Users\user\myprojects\byarent\env\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 904, in render_annotated
    return self.render(context)
  File "C:\Users\user\myprojects\byarent\env\lib\site-packages\django\template\defaulttags.py", line 512, in render
    return self.nodelist.render(context)
  File "C:\Users\user\myprojects\byarent\env\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 937, in render
    bit = node.render_annotated(context)
  File "C:\Users\user\myprojects\byarent\env\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 904, in render_annotated
    return self.render(context)
  File "C:\Users\user\myprojects\byarent\env\lib\site-packages\django\template\defaulttags.py", line 442, in render
    url = reverse(view_name, args=args, kwargs=kwargs, current_app=current_app)
  File "C:\Users\user\myprojects\byarent\env\lib\site-packages\django\urls\base.py", line 90, in reverse
    return iri_to_uri(resolver._reverse_with_prefix(view, prefix, *args, **kwargs))
  File "C:\Users\user\myprojects\byarent\env\lib\site-packages\django\urls\resolvers.py", line 622, in _reverse_with_prefix
    raise NoReverseMatch(msg)
django.urls.exceptions.NoReverseMatch: Reverse for 'cart_add' with arguments '('',)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['cart/add/(?P<house_id>[0-9]+)/$']
```

I have a shop and cart app here are the relevant views
/cart/view.py

```
@require_POST
def cart_add(request, house_id):
    cart = Cart(request)
    house = get_object_or_404(House, id=house_id)
    form = CartAddHouseForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        cd = form.cleaned_data
        cart.add(house=house,
                 quantity=cd['quantity'],
                 update_quantity=cd['update'])
    return redirect('cart:cart_detail')

def cart_remove(request, house_id):
    cart = Cart(request)
    house = get_object_or_404(House, id=house_id)
    cart.remove(house)
    return redirect('cart:cart_detail')

def cart_detail(request):
    cart = Cart(request)
    for item in cart:
        item['update_quantity_form'] = CartAddHouseForm(
                          initial={'quantity': item['quantity'],
                          'update': True})
    return render(request, 'cart/detail.html', {'cart': cart})
```

/shop/views.py

```
def house_list(request, category_slug=None):
    category = None
    categories = Category.objects.all()
    houses = House.objects.filter(available=True)
    if category_slug:
        category = get_object_or_404(Category, slug=category_slug)
        houses = houses.filter(category=category)
    return render(request,
                  'shop/house/list.html',
                  {'category': category,
                   'categories': categories,
                   'houses': houses})

def house_detail(request, id, slug):
    house = get_object_or_404(House,
                            id=id,
                            slug=slug,
                            available=True)
    cart_house_form = CartAddHouseForm()
    return render(request,
                'shop/house/detail.html',
                {'house': house,
                'cart_house_form':cart_house_form})
```

Here is the urls.py for the cart app

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.cart_detail, name='cart_detail'),
    path('add/<int:house_id>/',
         views.cart_add,
         name='cart_add'),
    path('remove/<int:house_id>/',
         views.cart_remove,
         name='cart_remove'),
]
```

The urls.py for my project

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('cart/', include('cart.urls', namespace='cart')),
    # path('orders/', include('orders.urls', namespace='orders')),
    path('', include('shop.urls', namespace='shop')),
]
```

The template where the error is being raised
/templates/shop/base.html

```
{% load static %}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <title>{% block title %}My shop{% endblock %}</title>
  <link href="{% static "css/base.css" %}" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
  <div id="header">
    <a href="/" class="logo">My shop</a>
  </div>
  <div id="subheader">
    <div class="cart">
      {% with total_items=cart|length %}
          {% if cart|length > 0 %}
            Your cart: 
            <a href="{% url "cart:cart_detail" %}">
              {{ total_items }} item{{ total_items|pluralize }},
              ${{ cart.get_total_price }}
            </a>
          {% else %}
            Your cart is empty.
          {% endif %}
        {% endwith %}
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="content">
    {% block content %}
    {% endblock %}
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

/templates/cart/detail.html

```
{% extends "shop/base.html" %}
{% load static %}

{% block title %}
  Your shopping cart
{% endblock %}

{% block content %}
  <h1>Your shopping cart</h1>
  <table class="cart">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Image</th>
        <th>House</th>
        <th>Quantity</th>
        <th>Remove</th>
        <th>Unit price</th>                
        <th>Price</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      {% for item in cart %}
        {% with house=item.house %}
          <tr>
            <td>
              <a href="{{ house.get_absolute_url }}">
                <img src="{% if house.image %}{{ house.image.url }}{% else %}{% static "img/no_image.png" %}{% endif %}">                    
              </a>
            </td>
            <td>{{ house.name }}</td>
            <td>
                <form action="{% url "cart:cart_add" house.id %}" method="post">
                    {{ item.update_quantity_form.quantity }}
                    {{ item.update_quantity_form.update }}
                    <input type="submit" value="Update">
                    {% csrf_token %}
                </form>
            </td>
            <td><a href="{% url "cart:cart_remove" house.id %}">Remove</a></td>
            <td class="num">${{ item.price }}</td>
            <td class="num">${{ item.total_price }}</td>
          </tr>
        {% endwith %}
      {% endfor %}
      <tr class="total">
        <td>Total</td>
        <td colspan="4"></td>
        <td class="num">${{ cart.get_total_price }}</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
  <p class="text-right">
    <a href="{% url "shop:house_list" %}" class="button light">Continue shopping</a>
    <a href="#" class="button">Checkout</a>
  </p>
{% endblock %}
```

Am still getting a hang of Django any help would be appreciated

Comment: Please show `cart/detail.html`.

Comment: @EndreBoth I have included it

Comment: From the error message it seems that you are passing an empty argument to `cart_add`. In places where you use `cart_add` in `detail.html`, comment it out and instead just display the argument you would pass to it (`house.id`). If no id is displayed, you need to find out why.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to change your url to this:

```
re_path(add/(?P<house_id>[0-9]+)/$',view.cart_add)
```